# "хотя бы" is a synonym for "по крайней мере"?

Tags: синонимы

Generally speaking without any context could we say that "**хотя бы**" is a synonym for "**по крайней мере**" meaning "at least"?

Answer (score 7):

These phrases synonymous in one of possible meanings - one that stands for English "at least". There are other meaning in which `хотя бы` can not be substituted, they are:

- As in "хоть бы зима поскорее кончилась!" (not that in modern Russian though there's a tendency to separate `хотя бы` from `хоть бы`, though actually the latter is just a shortened form.
- As in "взять бы 5й "Б" класс, вот хотя бы Петрова - совсем другие результаты".
- As in "хотя бы на час с тобой свидеться".

So basically when you use `хотя бы` for emphasizing it's interchangeable with `по крайней мере` to less extent. More on meaning and usages you can find [here](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D1%8B).

Comment: imho in modern Russian "хоть бы" and "хотя бы" have got a different meaning. "Хотя бы зима поскорее кончилась" can be translated as "At least, the winter could end"

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is even mentioned in dictionaries that "*хотя бы*" and "*по крайней мере*" are very close in their meanings.

[хотя бы](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D1%8B#%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) on Wiktionary:

> 1. усилительно-выделительная частица, то же, что хотя, хоть, близко по
>      значению к словам **по крайней мере, по меньшей мере**

[по крайней мере](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5#%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) on Wiktionary:

> 1. **хотя бы**, по меньшей мере